# How to query syntax class constituents as string of char?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Using elisp I am trying to convert from an emacs syntax class \s_ to a string of characters that constitute this class using the syntax table. I have not been able to find some reference code or an example that I could identify.

Does anyone have a reference or a code snippet to share?

Thanks, Matt

***Update 1*** : After further reading, I have found that the table can be traversed with [map-char-table](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char_002dTables.html#index-map_002dchar_002dtable-431), accumulating the required characters.

Comment: I'd start with the `describe-syntax` function.

Comment: I now see that the syntax table does not have a reverse lookup. I also see that its contents are not what I expected, with many chars defaulting to symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Some utilities in use here from

https://launchpad.net/s-x-emacs-werkstatt/

```
(defun ar-syntax-class-atpt (&optional pos)
  "Return the syntax class part of the syntax at point. "
  (interactive)
  (let* ((pos (or pos (point)))
     (erg (logand (car (syntax-after pos)) 65535)))
    (when (interactive-p) (message "%s" erg)) erg))

(defun syntax-class-bfpt ()
  "Return the syntax class part of the syntax at point. "
  (interactive)
  (let ((erg (logand (car (syntax-after (1- (point)))) 65535)))
    (when (interactive-p) (message "%s" erg)) erg))

(defun ar-syntax-atpt (&optional docu pos)
  (interactive)
  (when pos
    (goto-char pos))
  (let* ((elt (car (if (featurep 'xemacs)
                       (char-syntax (char-after))
                     (syntax-after (point)))))
         (stax (cond ((eq elt 0) "0 whitespace")
                     ((eq elt 5) "5 close parenthesis")
                     ((eq elt 10) "10 character quote")
                     ((eq elt 1) "1 punctuation")
                     ((eq elt 6) "6 expression prefix")
                     ((eq elt 11) "11 comment-start")
                     ((eq elt 2) "2 word")
                     ((eq elt 7) "7 string quote")
                     ((eq elt 12) "12 comment-end")
                     ((eq elt 3) "3 symbol")
                     ((eq elt 8) "8 paired delimiter")
                     ((eq elt 13) "13 inherit")
                     ((eq elt 4) "4 open parenthesis")
                     ((eq elt 9) "9 escape")
                     ((eq elt 14) "14 generic comment")
                     ((eq elt 15) "15 generic string"))))
    (when (interactive-p)
      (message (format "%s" stax)))
    (if docu
        (format "%s" stax)
      elt)))

(defun ar-syntax-in-region-atpt (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char beg)
    (let (erg)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (setq erg (concat erg "\n" "\"" (char-to-string (char-after)) "\"" "  is " (ar-syntax-atpt t)))
        (forward-char 1))
      (message "%s" erg)
      erg)))

(defun syntax-bfpt ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((stax (syntax-after (1- (point)))))
    (when (interactive-p)
      (message (format "%s" stax)))
    stax))
```

Comment: While I was after a mapping in the reverse direction, this is certainly a useful snippet for reference. Thanks.